# C++ Unable to Print Pointer Data of a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I'm dealing with a doubly Linked List. It's made up of classes and is centered around the current node (instead of a node in the beginning or end of the list). Now my print function will throw an error but only if I have traversed the list at all. My print function just prints data in the current node (providing it's not null). Here's my print function: (much more detailed description of my file hierarchy and code at the bottom)

```
void queue::print(){
    if (current){
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "+++++++++++++++++++ Webpage +++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl
            << "URL: " << current->data.getURL() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl 
            << "Title: " << current->data.getTitle() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl
            << "Content: " << current->data.getContent() << std::endl
            << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << std::endl << "Your not on a page. Please navigate to a page first." << std::endl;
    }
```

Now, if I've filled the list with two nodes of data, and I execute my print function, it'll print the data in the node just fine. However, if I traverse  to the previous node with my goBack() function:

```
void queue::goBack(){
    if (!current->previous){
        std::cout << "No previous page to go to!" << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        temp2 = current;
        current = current->previous;
    }
}
```

That will execute fine, but when I try to print the data in the node (with the same print function) I receive this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x003E7926 in Web Browser.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCE19.

and visual studio opens up a file without an extension type, with what looks like C code in it, called xstring, which has a break arrow pointing to line 1754 on it.

Now let me explain my code in a little more detail. I have five files: webQueue.h, webQueue.cpp, webPage.h, webPage.cpp, & main.cpp. All of the functions I've listed are in my webQueue.cpp file.

Here's webQueue.h:

```
#include "webPage.h"
class queue{
public:
    queue();
    void newPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c);
    void goForward();
    void goBack();
    void print();
private:
    struct Node{
        webPage data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };
    Node* temp;
    Node* current;
    Node* temp2;
};
```

And here's webPage.h:

```
#include <string>
class webPage{
public:
    webPage();
    webPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c);
    std::string getURL();
    void setURL(std::string u);
    std::string getTitle();
    void setTitle(std::string t);
    std::string getContent();
    void setContent(std::string c);
private:
    std::string URL;
    std::string title;
    std::string content;
};
```

My webQueue.cpp file includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "webQueue.h"
```

My webPage.cpp file just includes webPage.h and my main.cpp file (which contains my executing function) includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "webQueue.h"
```

Although these relations may seem a little convoluted, they should all be valid. The cpp files are linked to their header files with the exact same name (providing the header file exists), along with main.cpp being linked to webQueue.h and webQueue.h being linked to webPage.h. I can't see what I'm doing wrong with my code—although that's probably just because I'm having such a hard time understanding exactly how pointers work. I imagine that the error is in the code of my print(), goBack(), and goForward() functions (although I can't test my goForward() funtion until I fix my goBack() function) but I can't tell what's wrong.

Any help you guys can give would be greatly appreciated, as I am stumped. Here's a dropbox link to all the files so that you can test this program for yourself and see if I have any other functions with errors: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yekrz6dln1v9npk/webQueue.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I cannot overemphasize the importance of learning to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Pare your code down to the simplest example that still reproduces the error, and the bug will probably be obvious; if it isn't, you can post a small, self-contained example for us to look at.

Comment: @Beta That's the reason I included the dropbox download.

Comment: Visual Studio has cool debugging stuff, like breakpoints you can set at a line just before your program gets an unhandled exception. And a watch list, so you can see the values of the variables in your program. Please use those to see if the values are as you expect just before printing them.

Comment: You didn't read the help file. A *link* to a *zip file* of the *entire code base* is not a minimal complete example. I for one will not attempt to sift through your files.

Comment: Also, since Visual Studio was kind enough to stop and point at the error, odds are pretty good that it will also provide a stack trace so you can see where the program called a function that started the program on the way to its doom. Usually this stack trace will allow you to see the variables that went into the call. They may have been mangled by the crash so @KompjoeFriek 's advice holds, but the stack trace will tell you were to put the breakpoint so you can make the best use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Node` management is wrong.

One minor issue is that `queue::goBack()` and `queue::goForward()` are not checking if `current` is null before accessing its fields, so your code will crash if the user chooses to "go back" or "go forward" before choosing to "go to webpage" (at least `print()` is checking for null).  So add those checks, and maybe even update `printMenu()` to not even output those options when the queue does not have a current page available.

But more importantly, your `queue::newPage()` implementation is **completely broken**.  When `current` is not null, you are setting that node's `next` member to point at *itself* instead of the *new node* you have created, and you are not setting the new node's `previous` field *at all*, let alone to point at the existing node that it is being inserted after.

You should also get rid of the `temp` and `temp2` members of the `queue` class.  They do not belong there in the first place.  They are only useful inside of `queue::newPage()` (`queue::goBack()` does not need to use `temp` at all, just like `goForward()`), so they should be changed into local variables inside of `queue::newPage()` only.  Even better, they can just be removed altogether, as `queue::newPage()` can be implemented without using them at all.

Your `queue` implementation should look more like this instead (and this is not even counting copy/move semantics, either - see [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)):

```
#include "webPage.h"

class queue {
public:
    queue();
    void newPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c);
    void goForward();
    void goBack();
    void print();
private:
    struct Node {
        webPage data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };
    Node* current;
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "webQueue.h"

queue::queue() {
    current = nullptr;
}

void queue::newPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c) {
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->data = webPage(u, t, c);
    n->next = nullptr;
    n->previous = nullptr;

    if (current) {
        if (current->next) {
            n->next = current->next;
            current->next->previous = n;
        }
        n->previous = current;
        current->next = n;
    }

    current = n;
}

void queue::goBack() {
    if ((current) && (current->previous)) {
        current = current->previous;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No previous page to go to!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void queue::goForward() {
    if ((current) && (current->next)) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No next page to go to!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void queue::print() {
    if (current) {
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl
            << "+++++++++++++++++++ Webpage +++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl
            << "URL: " << current->data.getURL() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl 
            << "Title: " << current->data.getTitle() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl
            << "Content: " << current->data.getContent() << std::endl
            << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::endl << "You are not on a page. Please navigate to a page first." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And then, while you are at it, you should rewrite `queue` to stop using manual node management altogether and use the standard `std::list` class instead:

```
#include "webPage.h"
#include <list>

class queue {
public:
    void newPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c);
    void goForward();
    void goBack();
    void print();
private:
    std::list<webPage> data;
    std::list<webPage>::iterator current;
};
```

```
#include "webQueue.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

void queue::newPage(std::string u, std::string t, std::string c) {
    webPage p(u, t, c);
    if (data.empty()) {
        data.push_back(p);
        current = data.begin();
    }
    else {
        current = data.insert(std::next(current), p);
    }
}

void queue::goBack() {
    if ((!data.empty()) && (current != data.begin()))
        current = std::prev(current);
    else
        std::cout << "No previous page to go to!" << std::endl;
}

void queue::goForward() {
    if (!data.empty()) {
        std::list<webPage>::iterator iter = std::next(current);
        if (iter != data.end()) {
            current = iter;
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "No next page to go to!" << std::endl;
}

void queue::print() {
    if (!data.empty()) {
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl
            << "+++++++++++++++++++ Webpage +++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl
            << "URL: " << current->data.getURL() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl 
            << "Title: " << current->data.getTitle() << std::endl
            << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl
            << "Content: " << current->data.getContent() << std::endl
            << "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << std::endl << "You are not on a page. Please navigate to a page first." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my code, but why is the standard list better?

Comment: I'm also a little confused about this line of code: `current->next->previous = n;`. Is that just the equivalent of `current->next = n;` and `current->previous = n;`? I'm sorry to bother you, I just started learning C++ five months ago.

Comment: The `std::list` class is better to use because it is a *standardized* class defined in the C++ STL specification, and so it is portable to all C++ compilers, it has predictable behavior, handles all the dirty details of proper node management, etc. And no, `current->next->previous = n;` is NOT the same as `current->next = n; current->previous = n;`. Look REALLY hard at what those statements are doing...

Comment: `current->next->previous = n;` - when inserting your new node *in between two existing nodes*, the **next node** in the list needs to be updated to point at the new node that will now preceed it in the list, and the new node needs to point at that same *existing* node as it will now follow the new node in the list (the `n->next = current->next;` statement).

Comment: `current->next = n; current->previous = n;` - sets the **current node** to point at your new node on *both sides* of itself. This is completely wrong in any situation (how can a node existing in two places of the list at one time!), and ignores updating the **next** node in the list to point at its new preceeding node.

Comment: You should get yourself a really good tutorial/book that outlines linked-list management using diagrams that show how nodes are inserted and removed and how they refer to each other.  Or, just take the code above and draw it out for yourself at each step.